# How can i display Popup Modal forms in Rails activeadmin?

Tags: forms, modal-dialog, activeadmin, renderpartial

Hi I've just started using Rails Admin and I need to open popup modal form on certain model. To make it simple I would like to have a link which once clicked opens a modal form. How do I achieve this? I'm been browsing partial views and javascript in the gem to try to understand how this feature is achieved for example on one to many relations but the code is a bit beyond my knowledge and I can't get this done. Thanks

tied adding this,but don't know how this works.

action_item only: :new do
link_to('Click Here', "#", data: {toggle: "modal", target: "#modal"})
end

Comment: What exactly do you want inside the modal popup? A custom form?

Comment: its a Patient-to- Appointments relationship, in new appointment form , custom modal/popup is used to get patient object details.